# Figure placement on a baposter

Tags: horizontal-alignment, baposter, figure-placement, qrcode

I am working on a poster (`baposter`) using Latex, and I have a QR Code figure. I am trying to import it, but it keeps messing up the poster layout, as shown below.

[image]

I want to import it to be something like in the following picture:

[image]

Update :

I found a way around the problem by not using the Bib package and using the \node command and the Latex QR code instead of a generated image.

[baposter.cls](https://file.io/2oFQuUm6sP4O)

**Full Latex Code**

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
    \graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored
    \usepackage{adjustbox} % Add this line in your preamble
    \usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
    \usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode
    \usepackage{qrcode} % For generating QR codes
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
    \usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
    \usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
    \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
    
    \usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
    \setlength{\columnsep}{0.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns
    
    \usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template
    
    \newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
                \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
                \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
                \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
            }
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            \begin{document}
                \begin{poster}
                    {
                        headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
                        colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
                        bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
                        bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
                        borderColor=blue, % Border color
                        headerColorOne=blue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
                        headerColorTwo=blue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
                        headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
                        boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
                        textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
                        eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left  in the title and move the title left
                        headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
                        headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
                        headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
                        %textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
                        linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
                    }
                    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    %   TITLE SECTION 
                    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    %
                    %{\includegraphics[width=15em,height=7.5em]{UMILOGO2.png}} % Second university/lab logo on the right % First university/lab logo on the left
                    {\includegraphics[height=7.5em]{logo.png}} % Second university/lab logo on the right % First university/lab logo on the left
                    {\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont \bfseries\textsc{******************************************* Title *********************************} \vspace{0.4em}}
                    {\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont{\ XXXXX\textsuperscript{1,2}, XXXXXX\textsuperscript{1} \\ \textsuperscript{1} XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\ \textsuperscript{2} XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}} % Author names and institution
                    {\includegraphics[height=8em]{logo.png}} % Second university/lab logo on the right
                
                %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                % Introduction
                %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
                \headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,row=0}{
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                }
                
                %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                %   Objectifs
                %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
                \headerbox{Objectifs}{name=introduction,column=1,row=0,bottomaligned=introduction}{
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    \begin{enumerate}\compresslist
                        \item item;
                        \item item: 
                        \begin{itemize}\compresslist
                            \item item;
                            \item item;
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{enumerate}
                    \vspace{0.3em} % When there are two boxes, some whitespace may need to be added if the one on the right has more content
                }
                
                %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                %   construction
                %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                \headerbox{Propriétés}{name=construction,column=2,span=2,row=0}{
                    %\headerbox{Conclusion}{name=conclusion,column=2,span=2,row=0,below=results,above=references}{
                        \begin{multicols}{2}
                            - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                            {\includegraphics[height=13.5em]{logo.png}} 
                            \begin{center}
                                \captionof*{table}{\textbf{Propriétés thermophysiques}[1]}
                                \begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
                                    \toprule
                                    \textbf{$\lambda$ [W/m.K]} & \textbf{$\rho$ [kg/m$^3$]} & \textbf{$c_{p}$ [kJ/kg.K]}& \textbf{$e$ [m]}\\
                                    \midrule
                                    0.036& 30 & 1500 & 0.2\\
                                    \bottomrule
                                \end{tabular}
                            \end{center}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                            \begin{center}
                                \centering
                                \captionsetup{skip=0.1\baselineskip} % Adjust the skip value as needed
                                \captionof*{table}{\textbf{Propriétés }}
                                \begin{tabular}{l c c c}
                                    \toprule
                                    & & \textbf{Réf} \\
                                    \midrule
                                    Température de consigne & -20±2°C& \\
                                    Température d'évap. & -24°C & \\
                                    Réfrigérant & R455A& [2] \\
                                    Capacité Frigo. du compresseur & ***** W& [3] \\
                                    Puissance du compresseur & ***** W& [3] \\
                                    Puissance de dégivrage & ***** W& [4] \\
                                    %       \bottomrule
                                \end{tabular}
                            \end{center}
                    \end{multicols} }
                    
                    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    %   REFERENCES
                    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    %\headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0,above=bottom}{
                        %%\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
                        %%\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
                        %%\small{ % Reduce the font size in this block
                            %%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
                            %%\bibliography{sample} % Use sample.bib as the bibliography file
                            %%}{\hspace{5em}{\includegraphics[height=5em]{REF1.png}}
                            %}}
                    \headerbox{Références}{name=references,column=0,span=1,above=bottom}{
                        %\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
                        %\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
                        %\small{ % Reduce the font size in this block
                            %\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
                            %\bibliography{sample} % Use sample.bib as the bibliography file
                            %}
                        \begin{tikzpicture}
                            \node at (-2.5,0.40) {\textbf{Pour les références, veuillez }};
                            %       \node{{\hspace{7em}

    {\includegraphics[height=5.5em]{REF1.png}}}};
                                %\node{\hspace{7em}\textcolor{blue}{\qrcode[height=5.5em,version=5]{https://me-qr.com/l/References-Pour-Le-Poster-Du-SIAM2024}}};
                                \node{\hspace{7em}\textcolor{black}{\qrcode[height=5.5em,version=5]{}}};
                                \node at (-2.5,-0.1) {\textbf{scanner le code QR.}};
                            \end{tikzpicture}
                        }
                        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        %   FUTURE RESEARCH
                        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        \headerbox{Perspectives }{name=futureresearch,column=1,span=2,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block
                            
                            \begin{multicols}{2}
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
                                
                                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
                            \end{multicols}
                        }
                        
                        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        %   CONTACT INFORMATION
                        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        \headerbox{Information et contact }{name=contact,column=3,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block
                            {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.. 
                                
                                - \textbf{Web:} \textit{www.web.org}
                                
                                - \textbf{E-mail:} \textit{xxxxx@email.com}
                        }}
                        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        %   RESULTS 1
                        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        \headerbox{Résultats}{name=results,column=2,span=2,row=0,below=construction,above=references}{
                            %\headerbox{Results}{name=results,column=2,span=2,row=0}{
                                
                                \begin{multicols}{2}
                                    \vspace{1em}
                                    \begin{center}
                                        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{placeholder}
                                        \captionof*{figure}{Figure caption}
                                    \end{center}
                                    
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit 
                                \end{multicols}
                                
                                %------------------------------------------------
                                
                                \begin{multicols}{2}
                                \vspace{1em}
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                
                                \begin{center}
                                    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{placeholder}
                                    \captionof*{figure}{Figure caption}
                                \end{center}
                                
                            \end{multicols}
                        }
                        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        %   MATERIALS AND METHODS
                        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        \headerbox{Matériels et Méthodes}{name=method,column=0,span=2,below=introduction,bottomaligned=results}{ % This block's bottom aligns with the bottom of the conclusion block
                            \begin{multicols}{2}
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ullamco laboris nisi ut ullamco laboris nisi ut
                                
                                \hspace{4em} {\includegraphics[height=6em]{logo.png}} 
                                
                                - La capacité de refroidissement et la consommation d'énergie du compresseur sont représentées à l'aide de courbes de performance définies par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.; ullamco laboris nisi ut ullamco laboris nisi ut
                                \begin{equation} 
                                    X=P_{bicubic}(\alpha,SDT,SST)
                                \end{equation}
                                %\textit{\textbf{X}}: la puissance ou la capacité de refroidissement (W)\\
                                \textit{\textbf{$\alpha$}}: les coefficients ;\\
                                \textbf{\textit{SDT}} : température  (°C);\\
                                \textbf{\textit{SST}} : température  (°C);\\
                                
                                - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.; 
                                \begin{equation}
                                    Heat_{Rejected}=P_{linear}(\beta,T_{cond},T_{db})
                                \end{equation}
                                %\textit{\textbf{X}}: la puissance ou la capacité de refroidissement (W)\\
                                \textit{\textbf{$\beta$}}: les coefficients ;\\
                                
                                - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.;
                                
                                - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua;
                                
                                \hspace{0em} {\includegraphics[height=11em]{logo.png}} 
                                \captionsetup{skip=1pt} % Adjust the space here
                                \captionof*{figure}{\textbf{Variation } [7]}
                                \vspace{-0.5em} % Adjust the value as per your need
                                \begin{center}
                                    \centering
                                    \captionsetup{skip=1pt} % Adjust the space here
                                    \captionof*{table}{\textbf{Propriétés thermophysiques } [7]}
                                    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
                                        \toprule
                                        \textbf{$T_{m}$} & \textbf{$\lambda$} & \textbf{$\rho$} & \textbf{$c_{p}$}& \textbf{$e$}\\
                                        °C  & W/m.K & kg/m$^3$ & kJ/kg.K & m\\
                                        \midrule
                                        -17/-18 & 0.6 & 1200 & 2 & 0.02\\
                                        \bottomrule
                                    \end{tabular}
                                \end{center}
                            \end{multicols}
                        }
                    \end{poster}
                \end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should not set whole words in math mode. Look at the word "Rejected",  the spacing between the letters is all messed up.

Comment: Code fragments really don't help. But probably the simplest solution would be to use two `minipage` environments side by side, one for the references and one for the qrcode.

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for your comment.
I have updated the code as you suggested.

Comment: The code does not compile for me.

Comment: I guess you need the baposter.cls document class to compile. You can download it following this link https://file.io/2oFQuUm6sP4O

Comment: There are too many `}` in your code. You should fix this error first before worrying about your layout.

Comment: People might want to look at the contents of a file before downloading it, rather than following some random link. I think, the class you use is this one: https://github.com/anriseth/baposter . Note that we don't have the images you use. Consider replacing them with `example-image`